# Segmentation fault (core dumped) using char*

Tags: c

i am new to c programming. i am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) when i am
    trying to print the string. please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char *ptr;
  strcpy(ptr, "mystring");
  printf( "%s\n", ptr);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use the value of a variable until you assign it one.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't allocated any memory for your pointer to point at.

```
char array[MAX_LEN + 1];

char *ptr = array;

strncpy(ptr, "Cadence", MAX_LEN);
ptr[MAX_LEN] = '\0';

printf( "%s\n", ptr);
```

Please note that `strncpy()` *can be* a safer way to copy strings, since we specify the maximum number of characters to copy, which makes it harder to overrun the string and 'scribble' memory.

**Update** in response to comments: I've altered the above code to use a slightly safer pattern. You might also want to investigate `strlcpy()` (non-standard library).

Comment: strncpy is part of standard library. But it's really not safer version of strcpy().

Comment: I don't know _why_ people keep insisting that `strncpy` is somehow safer, it's not. Yes, if you try to copy too much data, it will prevent immediate buffer overflow. But then, go and try to use that non-NUL terminated string in any other stringy way, like `strlen` for example. Go on, give it a shot. I'll wait right here :-) Its main problem is that, when it fails, it neither tells you NOR gives you a usable string.

Comment: That's better though, technically, `strcpy` can _also_ be a safer way to copy strings if you add certain pre-checks to it :-)

Comment: I missed your edit of the comment. @Paxdiablo has given the reason. If you think, specifying length makes it safer, then it's also error prone when the source string has more bytes than the length. To put it simply, **strncpy is as safe/unsafe as strcpy.**

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `char *ptr;`, you allocate memory for a pointer to a char. But if you want to put a string inside the char, it will make an overflow.

Therefore, you have to allocate memory for your string :

char str[1024]; // which is the maximum string lenth that you will be able to put in str.

Furthemore, don't forget the null terminator (`\0`) that terminate every string and has the size of one char